# SQL - making several groupings (performance)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some SQL query that founds records based on provided parameters. That query is pretty heavy, so I want to execute it less as possible.

After I getting result from that query, I need to perform its breakdown.

For example, consider the following query:

```
SELECT location, department, industry
FROM data
WHERE ...
```

After that, I need to perform breakdown of that results, e.g. I need to provide list of all locations where from I have results and counts of each type, same for departments and same for industries.

As I know, in order to get breakdown by locations, I need to perform GROUP BY (location) and then count.

My question is: is it possible, for performance considerations, to perform several groupings/ counts on query result without recalculating it over and over again for each grouping?

Comment: Yes you can, in various ways, but your question is very broad. If you give more details, it's easier to give a more detailed answer too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Unless I misunderstood you.

You need to use [windowed functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx). For instance:

```
SELECT location
    , department
    , industry
    , COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY location, department)
    , COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY location, department, industry)
FROM data
WHERE ...;
```

Keep in mind, that doing a `COUNT(DISTINCT column)` is not possible.

Comment: Yep, that's it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can do what you want with `grouping sets` (documented [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb522495(v=SQL.105).aspx)):

```
SELECT location, department, industry, count(*)
FROM data
WHERE ...
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((location), (department), (industry))
```

This will return rows like:

```
location1    NULL     NULL    10
. . .
NULL         dept1    NULL    17
. . .
```

If you want to get fancy, and you have no `NULL` values in any of the columns, you can do:

```
SELECT (case when location is not null then 'location'
             when department is not null then 'department'
             when industry is not null then 'industry'
        end) as which,
       coalesce(location, department, industry) as name, count(*)
FROM data
WHERE ...
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((location), (department), (industry))
ORDER BY which;
```

You can actually do the same thing using the `GROUPING()` function, if you do have `NULL` values in the columns, but you have to replace the `coalesce()` as well.